# Is there an AJAX web client that can connect to ejabberd?

Tags: ajax, chat, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm looking for a way to host an AJAX web client on my jabber server for people that can't install a real jabber client.

I tried JWchat but it hasn't been updated since 2004 and doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is:
Strophe.js http://strophe.im/strophejs/ is pretty much what most people use currently. You can find the code here: https://github.com/metajack/strophejs